# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error de Java manejando una matriz

Tags: java, netbeans, matrices

No se cómo solucionar este error:

> error: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Me lleva a la siguiente clase, en la función de `setFilas`, que la empleo para insertar una fila en una matriz.

```
package arrays;

public class Matriz 
{
    private int matriz[][];


    public Matriz(int numFil, int numCol)
    {
        numFil = 0;
        numCol = 0;
        matriz = new int[numFil][numCol];
    }

     public int[][] getMatriz(){
        return matriz;
    }

    public void setMariz(int [][] matriz)
    {
        this.matriz = matriz;
    }

    public int getNumFilas()
    {
        return matriz.length; //Devuelve el número de filas de la matriz
    }

    public int getNumColumnas()
    {
        return matriz[0].length; //Devuelve el número de columnas de la matriz
    }

    public int getValor(int fil, int col)
    {
        return matriz[fil][col];
    }

    public void setValor(int fil, int col, int valor)
    {
        matriz[fil][col] = valor;
    }

    public int[] getFila(int fil)
    {
        return matriz[fil];
    }

    **public void setFila(int fil, int[] array) 
    {
        matriz[fil] = array;
    }**

}
```

La llamo aquí:

```
public Matriz vuelcaFichMatriz(Array adim)
    {
        Matriz matriz = new Matriz(adim.getValor(0), adim.getValor(1));
        int fila=0;
        String linea = leerLinea();
        while(linea != null)
        {
            ArrayString as = new ArrayString();
            as.arraySt = linea.split(" ");      //Pongo en cada posición del array de strings un número
            Array a = new Array(adim.getValor(1));

            for(int i=0; i < as.arraySt.length; i++)    //Recorro el array que me ha creado split
            {
                String cad = as.getValor(i);
                int n = Integer.parseInt(cad);  //Convierto cada String a int
                a.setValor(i, n);               //Lo meto en un array de enteros
            }

            matriz.setFila(fila, a.getArray());    
            fila++;
            linea = leerLinea();

        }
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de cuando llamas a la función? Ese error hace referencia a que estas poniendo un *indice* mayor al tamaño del array

Comment: Le he puesto el código, siento que se vea así, soy nueva en stackoverflow y no se muy bien como va. Gracias

Comment: Cuando quieres darle formato al código, lo mas optimo y cómodo es: *seleccionar todo el código y presionar "ctr+k"*

Answer (score 2):

---

Saludos, Gloria.

La excepción:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Nos indica que el índice que estás intentando ingresar en el arreglo está fuera de sus dimensiones, es decir, que tu arreglo **no tiene un índice 0**, y la verdad, tiene mucho sentido si vemos el constructor de tu clase `Matriz`:

```
public Matriz(int numFil, int numCol) {
    numFil = 0;
    numCol = 0;
    matriz = new int[numFil][numCol];
}
```

¿Por qué asignas `numFil = 0;` y `numCol = 0;`? Básicamente, estarías diciendo esto:

```
matriz = new int[0][0];
```

**¡Esto es un arreglo sin ningún espacio!** Y por ende, al intentar ingresar en el primer espacio de tu arreglo, te saltará la excepción.

Realmente las dos asignaciones que haces en el constructor están de más, deberías quitarlas y dejarlas así:

```
public Matriz(int numFil, int numCol) {
    matriz = new int[numFil][numCol];
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Recuerda marcar esta respuesta, si es la respuesta correcta.